# SQL - modify text for particular row entries

Tags: sql, view, format

Suppose that I have one column in SQL from a simple SELECT statement.

How can I modify the text of particular row entries without overwriting the data?

I am looking at indenting some particular entries for a table I am creating in VS (e.g. every entry that is called 'Name' will be changed to '   Name'). So I want to modify my SQL query to change some particular fields to be indented when they are called.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which SQL dialect are you using? MS SQL Server/T-SQL? PL-SQL (Oracle)? MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL you can use [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
SELECT REPLACE(field, 'Name', ' Name')
```

For Oracle you can do [translate](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php)

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(...).
```

you can also do this in both MySQL and T-SQL via a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement too.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql...

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET NAME = CONCAT(' ', NAME) WHERE ...
```

Comment: I believe the requirement was NOT to modify the data.

Comment: the op says **"without overwriting the data"** so doesn't want to update the data `SELECT id, CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(' ', name) as c_name FROM tbl;`

Comment: @mike It's ok -- that thought crossed my mind initially too :)